# How to get your personalized library widget in QT design window?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qml

I am a newbie to QT.
My goal is to  access my personalized widget(created in my DLL) from the Design window of application in QT.
I was able to create the DLL successfully and call it from my application. 
Kindly guide me as to how to access the DLL widget which I created in the design window along with other library QML types.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Please find my files below :

**myCppLib.h**

```
#ifndef MYCPPLIB_H
#define MYCPPLIB_H

#include "mycpplib_global.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>

class MYCPPLIBSHARED_EXPORT MyCppLib : public QWidget
{
private:
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyCppLib();

    void Test();

    //void resize(int, int);

    //void show();

};

#endif // MYCPPLIB_H
```

Application 
**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <mycpplib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    MyCppLib testLib;
    //testLib.resize(200,200);
    testLib.setProperty("height", 250);
    testLib.setProperty("width", 250);
    testLib.Test();
    testLib.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean getting acces to it from qtDesigner like described here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html ? Edit: what version of qt, what version of tools, what ide, ... ?

Comment: Your text is missing a description of the problems you have with your code.

Comment: The above code works just fine. But am trying to come up with a code that gets the contents of 'myCpp.lib' in the QML types window. I want to be able to drag and drop my personal widgets to the panel in the design widow of QT. Yes, like mentioned in the link " doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html". I am using QTCreator 5.3 version.